Local git commit in Visual Studio 2022 results in "The pipe has been ended"
After creating the ASP.NET Core MVC web app in Visual Studio 2022, I tried to commit changes in local branch in Visual Studio, but every time, I get this error:

The pipe has been ended

enter image description here

You can see the complete output from GIT in the output pane if you select version control.

On the side note - why are you trying to commit .vs and bin folders? Looks like you should consider adding vs .gitignore

.gitignore visual studio worked, thank you


After creating the ASP.NET Core MVC web app in Visual Studio 2022, I
tried to commit changes in local branch in Visual Studio, but every
time, I get this error: The pipe has been ended

Well, as @Guru Stron already pointed out why you are having the trouble, furthermore, I am extending the resolution so that it might be helpful for step by step implementation.
According to your screenshot I noticed that your bin and vs files also been considered as commit list which is incorrect.

By default, Visual Studio tries to include .vs and bin folders in Git commits. These folders are typically excluded as they contain temporary or build-related files.
So, in your Git ignore settings you shouldn't not include these two folders.
Thus, if you go to your solution explorer as following:

You must exclude those two folders in order to fix your issue. See the reference below:


this did not resolve the problem for me as i do not have those folders included but also have the error
